# Can't echo POST but can echo REQUEST

Tags: php, forms, post

**EDIT: Figured it out, as mentioned in my comment. Did a stupid and used a single = instead of double in the if statement. What we do learn from my post is you shouldn't try to code after an 8 hour shift and very little sleep.**

Seem to have an odd problem, I can't seem to echo any of my $_POST variables but if I access them with $_REQUEST it's fine.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);
//Session start
session_start();

//Adding a story
var_dump($_POST);
echo $_REQUEST['title'];

//Get, check & clean variables
if ($_SESSION['login'] != 1) {
    echo 'Not logged in';
} else {
    $user = $_SESSION['UID'];
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["title"]);
    $desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
    $date = time();

    //Add story to DB
    echo "<br />User: $user  Title: $title  Desc: $desc   Date: $date";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `cl-stories` (title,user,date,description) VALUES ('$title', '$user', '$date', '$desc')";
}
```

So the `echo $_REQUEST['title'];` at the top works fine but using `$_POST['title']` does nothing. The variables are there if I var_dump POST contents.

It must be something simple I'm missing because it's working on all my other pages.
It seems very similar to my previous question but I'm not making that mistake again.

Here's what it outputs:

```
array(3) { ["title"]=> string(6) "Blergh" ["description"]=> string(17) "Story description" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" } Blergh
User: 1 Title: Desc: Date: 1326260553
```

Note the lack of anything after Title: and Desc:

Form if it helps:

```
<form method="post" action="cl-addStory.php">
<input type="text" name="title" size="22" value="Title">
<textarea name="description" value="Description" rows="6">Story description</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: If `variables are there if I var_dump POST` then it should work

Comment: You could try concatenating your string and your variables: `VALUES (" . $title . ", " . $user . ", "` etc.

Comment: Tried, but realised nothing is going into the variables. Can't even echo out the POST variable on it's own eg echo $_POST['title'];

Comment: Try echoing out `$_POST['title']` just under your `var_dump` to confirm that none of your intervening code is clearing it. Also, try echoing title directly, rather than filtering it out without calling the mysql function

Comment: Interesting, I can `echo $_POST['title'];` now but cannot do anything with the `$title` variable. Even without escaping it.

Comment: Oh no...it's obvious. Didn't compare properly in the IF, should be `==` not single `=`. Chalk up one more fail on the idiot board.

Comment: Take a step back and setup a test page. Just to confirm there's nothing wrong with your environment (unlikely)

Comment: is the database updated?

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any errors, i've tried your form in a separte page and it worked well. Have a look at this code:

```
<?php

echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);echo "</pre>";
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="title" size="22" value="Title">
<textarea name="description" value="Description" rows="6">Story description</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Place this code in separate file  and test it.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a problem where an error in some browsers (Chrome in my example) would submit the form twice (even though the submit button was clicked once, and it only looked as the page was refreshed once). So the browser would submit one time WITH the contents provided in the form, and another time - a split second after - with an empty form.

It could be this you're experiencing. I solved it by using

```
if (!empty($_POST)){ ... }
```

Hope it helps.